# How to determine if a user belongs to a certain group using ASP.Net Identity Framework 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Using the new ASP.Net Identity Framework 2.0, I am trying to determine the list of users that belong to a certain group.

The UserManager and RoleManager are properly instantiated and I get the right infos while debugging but I don't understand how to use user.Roles.Contains.

```
var _listAllUsers = UserManager.Users.ToListAsync().Result;
//var _allUsers = UserManager.Users;
var roleToMatch = RoleManager.FindByNameAsync("MyUserManager").Result;
foreach (var user in _listAllUsers){
var _listGroupAdminCat = user.Roles.Contains((IdentityUserRole)roleToMatch);
}
```

There's something I am missing in the syntax.

Comment: don't forget to use the "await" keyword when using Async methods. As written, you'll never get the right results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get your `IdentityRole` object:

```
var role = RoleManager.FindByName("MyUserManager");
```

Then get the users in that role:

```
var usersInRole = role.Users;
```

Your question title is asking a slightly different question though, how to determine is a user is in a role. For this, use the `UserManager` like this:

```
int userId = 5;
string roleToCheck = "MyRole";
bool userIsInRole = userManager.IsInRole(5, roleToCheck );
```

It's also worth noting that in the code you posted you are using the asynchronous functions incorrectly. Either use them with the `await` keyword or use the synchronous versions:

```
var roleSynchronously = RoleManager.FindByName("MyUserManager");
var roleAsynchronously = await RoleManager.FindByNameAsync("MyUserManager");
```

Comment: thanks you so much ! in fact I didn't imagined it was possible to find users in the role.
Concerning the await keyword, I get a compile error if I use it: Error 3 The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task<System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult>'

Comment: Maybe should I post another question concerning the error I get when using the await keyword ?

Comment: There's lots of good tutorials on async/await, just Google them!